# Should I add encounters to help level my players before moving on to a new adventure that starts at a higher level?

Tags: dnd-5e, published-adventures, experience-points, lost-mine-of-phandelver

Me and the boys played D&D, Lost Mine of Phandelver, but only got to level 4.

What are the pros and cons of either making them fight some more monsters, or just go to the next campaign and make them level 5?

Comment: Are you asking about pros and cons of taking either course of action?   As asked, this question will probably be closed as "opinon based."  Welcome to RPGSE.  [Tour], [Ask] and [Answer] provide some guidance on how this Q&A site works.

Comment: Welcome to RPG.SE! Take the [tour] if you haven't already, and check out the [help] for more guidance. Let us know if the current question is what you're trying to ask; if not, please edit the question to clarify.

Answer (score 8):

### You can either level them up or plunge in; you are the DM.

The question you want to ask yourself is: which sounds like more fun to  you?

#### Advantages of running some more encounters:

1. You get to try your hand at creating encounters.  That's good, practical DM experience to gain.  I ran various older editions, and until I DM'd in this edition I could not get a feel for encounter difficulty / creation).

   - Why I'd suggest this option, based on my own experience: crafting a few encounters, or a few "side quests", is as much for your benefit as theirs.  I think it will improve your DM instincts once you have done this a few times.
2. No spoilers (in case the players are checking out the books behind your back) since not even you know what the monsters will be yet!  8^)

#### Disadvantages of running some more encounters:

1. You have to put in a bit more work as DM.
2. You may make a mis-estimate of the encounter difficulty.  (But you
   can adapt on the fly, and this may not impact the fun)

#### Advantages of just going to the next book

1. Less work for you.
2. The players get immersed in the next adventure sooner.

#### Disadvantages of just going to the next book

As the boys are new players, skipping levels may make it harder for them to understand their mechanics.

#### And one last option: go forth but not level them up (for completeness)

This can either result in a "sink or swim" kind of challenge, and they might surprise you with how well they do, or, you may need to adjust the encounters down as they are intended for level 5 characters.  There is a *substantial* power change for the PC's when going up from level 4 to level 5.

- Spell casters (wizards, druids, bards, clerics, warlocks, sorcerers) have access to third level spells which are a notable power boost.
- Martial characters (Fighters, Barbarians, Rangers, Monks, Paladins) get two attacks per turn.

Comment: @Carcosa here is the original text *Should I make then fight some more monsters or just go to the next campaign and make them level 5* and people keep editing the question.  I answered the original question.  I edited out kids, thanks for catching that.

Comment: Does... your quoted section not indicate that the party will be made level 5 when they go to the next adventure, even if not made to fight more monsters? If so, why would encounters need to be adjusted down?

Comment: @Carcosa I see what you are getting at. Edited. Thanks.